# How to end the lifecycle of a removed View?

Tags: android, android-view, android-lifecycle

When I create, add and remove views within one activity, what is the lifecycle of the removed views? They could be removed with `removeView()` or `removeAllViews()`.

Are they available for garbage collection immediately upon removing or do they stay until the activity goes away? For example because of any register of all views attached or not.

Should I do additional steps to get them available for garbage collection quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `View` you have created programatically then you would need to ensure two things to make sure the `View` is GC'd.

1. Call `removeView()` from the `ViewGroup` where you added the `View`. This is because a `ViewGroup` will maintain a reference to the children.
2. Make sure you aren't maintaining any references to the `View` in your code, for instance as a field of the `Activity` class. Maintaining a reference to the `View` in this way will prevent it from being GC'd.

There are several good articles about how to avoid memory leaks, including [this one](https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8)

Comment: Thank you. So I have to care for my own references but I don't need to fear any hidden references from the side of the Android framework with respect to views.

Comment: @Blcknx that's basically right. The `View` classes behave as per ordinary Java objects.

Comment: @Blcknx would you consider accepting the answer (green tick) if you found it helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the link to a very useful article.